# Better way of compressing a String

Tags: scala

I am trying the Hackerrank problem where the problem is

Problem Statement

```
Input: abcaaabbb
output : abca3b3
```

My solution looks like

```
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine

object Solution {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val input = readLine()
        require(input.length > 0, "input string must not be empty.")    
        println(compress(input.tail, input.head, 1, ""))
    }

    def compress(in: String, currentChar: Char, currentCharCount: Int, out: String):String = in.isEmpty match {
        case true => getNewOutput(out, currentChar, currentCharCount)
        case false => in.head match {
            case `currentChar` => compress(in.tail, currentChar, currentCharCount + 1, out)
            case _ => compress(in.tail, in.head, 1, getNewOutput(out, currentChar, currentCharCount))
        }
    }

    def getNewOutput(out:String, currentChar: Char, currentCharCount:Int):String = 
        out + currentChar + (if(currentCharCount == 1) "" else currentCharCount.toString)
}
```

This works well, but timeouts on two test cases. I am wondering what is taking lot of time?

is it the `match`? or `tail`?

What is a better way to write it?

P.S. I am learning `Scala` so bear with my syntax and knowledge at this moment

Comment: tail is quick. Not tried it, but it might be building up the out string character by character. Try a stringbuilder, or just create a list of chars and convert to a string later?

Comment: I agree with @TheArchetypalPaul, your problem may be reinstantiating strings. I'd also convert it to a `List[Char]`, this is the most efficient collection for your approach because `head` and `tail` are both O(1) operations on it.

Comment: How do these timeout test cases look like in size and quantity/distribution of repetitions?

Comment: why are you doing a true/false match instead of an `if`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As problem is marked as *Functional Programming / **Recursion*** it is expected to be solvable via tail recursion. Usual approach for tailrec in such sequence traversal is creating additional accumulator parameter which is handled on very end:

```
def compress(str: Seq[Char], acc: List[(Char, Int)]): String = str match {
    case first +: rest => compress(rest, acc match {
      case (`first`, n) :: tail => (first, n + 1) :: tail
      case _ => (first, 1) :: acc
    })
    case _ => acc.reverse.view.map {
      case (c, 1) => c.toString
      case (c, n) => s"$c$n"
    }.mkString
  }
```

Although tail recursive functions like that are rarely considered as good style FP because of poor composablitity. Usualy nicer solutions use folding instead of tailrec:

```
def compress(str: Seq[Char]): String =
  str.foldLeft(List.empty[(Char, Int)]) { (acc, char) =>
    acc match {
      case (`char`, n) :: tail => (char, n + 1) :: tail
      case _ => (char, 1) :: acc
    }
  }.reverse.view.map {
    case (c, 1) => c.toString
    case (c, n) => s"$c$n"
  }.mkString
```

I did actually bother to verify that both solutions are **Accepted** on corresponding Hackerrank problem with code

```
object Solution {
  def compress(...
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(compress(io.StdIn.readLine()))
  }
}
```

And second `foldLeft` implementation is somewhat faster.

The most trouble in you code is `String` concatenation. As problem is awaiting 100K-character String results in some places, your

```
out + currentChar + ...
```

was appending small parts to very long prefixes many times. As `String` in scala is plain old `java.lang.String`, not like `Vector` which could effectively reuse large parts in small concatenations it was beating you down to TL.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is very helpful. One question though. why did you use `view` after `reverse` and not before? Like `view.reverse.map` vs `reverse.view.map`? The answer still remains same, but if the Input is very long `reverse.view` may fail with `OOM` but `view.reverse` will not, right?

Comment: @daydreamer If you look at how actually [`reverse` is implemented for `view`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8cc66b0a8fb6c8c46c306a672a66cf5af431f733/src/library/scala/collection/SeqViewLike.scala#L151) You'll see that it creates intermediate reversed list anyway, so it's more efficient to just drop first `List` as garbage than have both in memory

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution based in `span` proves `O(n)` and it is simple to implement, as follows,

```
def compress(s: String): String = {
  if (s.isEmpty) s
  else {
    val (l,r) = s.span(_ == s.head)
    (if (l.size == 1) l else l.head + l.size.toString) + compress(r)
  }
}
```

On the left of span we gather same characters to a current head, which are then prepended to the final result either as a single character or as a character with the number of consecutive repetitions; on the right of span we have the remaining of the string to be compressed, until we consume the entire string.

**Update**: as commented below, and following the original enquiry, note this tail-recursive version of the initial recursive proposal,

```
def compress(s: String): String = {

  def f(s2: String, res: String): String = {
    if (s2.isEmpty) res
    else {
      val (l,r) = s2.span(_ == s2.head)
      f(r, res + (if (l.size == 1) l else l.head + l.size.toString))
    }
  }

  f(s, "")
}
```

Comment: And unlike the  original, is not tail-recursive